# To calculate change in lines of code between 2 changesets

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have a requirement for which i need to find out the difference between the lines of code on one change set to other in Visual Studio. I need to calculate the number of lines changed after check in of new code.
If it was a single file i could go in and compare with the previous version to view the changes. But this requirement is for finding the LOC count between various files after multiple check ins.

I am looking at options in TFS to do this but any comments here would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just checkout the original version, [count](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/) the lines of code, then update to the next version and count again?

Comment: Thats what i did for time being. But it is a bit cumbersome with a lot of different people adding code to the same solution.

Comment: It might be worth customising you build process to do this and output the results with your build report? I'll post some steps if you want?

Comment: That will be most helpful Dave. But not sure how it will be useful in finding the difference in LOC. The reason is that multiple check ins will be made and i will require only a few changesets to be merged back and get the LOC count. But please do post the steps of what you are proposing. I will look into this and see if i can customize it for my use. Thanks a ton for your response.

Comment: I was thinking of making it so each build outputs the total number of lines of code for that build. Then you can just look at each build to see how many lines there are.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for the [Code Churn and Run Coverage perspectives from the SQL Server Analysis Services cube for Visual Studio Team Foundation Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244661(v=vs.100).aspx) (link is to 2010 version since you tagged the question as 2010):

> By using these perspectives, you can view just the measures, dimensions, and attributes that are associated with the **changes in lines of codes** and the extent to which code is covered in builds and test runs.